# How to get a HTTPS web page?

Tags: http, sockets, visual-c++, ssl, https

I wrote a *Visual C++* aplication that connected to a web server and sended a request:

```
/GET /file.htm
Host: www.server.com
```

Then I obtained the file.

Currently, the server changed to HTTP secure, and I obtain a response like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.server.com/file.htm
```

Theres a way to modify my code adding some lib, or similar, to get a *https* page?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) from [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx)

example:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815657

or if you're not using managed c++, use [HttpOpenRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168151